# Is ECDH easier than DH to be broken?

Tags: diffie-hellman, ecc

*As I am a security newbie, this post might have lots of misconceptions about security. If so, please let me know*

I've heard that ECDH is preferable to DH because its smaller key size and lower computational overhead.

Then thinking reversely, isn't it easy to reveal a private key from a public key of ECDH? Or, is it nearly impossible to do it (because private key and public key is not 1:1 relationship?)

Comment: You might want to read this: ["Why are key lengths in asymmetric algorithms typically longer than key lengths in symmetric algorithms?"](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/46852/why-are-key-lengths-in-asymmetric-algorithms-typically-longer-than-key-lengths-i)  The question compares symmetric and asymmetric crypto, but the answer generalizes to comparisons between different asymmetric algorithms.

Comment: I am sorry, but aren't elliptic curve diffie hellman and (origianl) diffie hellman categorized into the same category?

Comment: Jeon, they're both asymmetric, yes, but the same reasons that asymmetric algorithms have longer keys than symmetric ones also explain why some asymmetric algorithms have longer keys than others.  It's a function of the best algorithms for attacking the algorithms; the algorithms for attacking 256-bit ECDH are comparable in cost to those for attacking 3072-bit DH.

Comment: Ah okay, I was too hasty. I will read it carefully, thanks

Comment: Math behind ECDH is much simpler than in traditional DH, hence it is quicker.

Comment: Well, I am reading the article given by Luis Casillas, so I am not complaining about it. But to clarify, my original question is, "if ECDH is quicker, isn't it easier to be broken? if so, if not so, what is a reason?"

Comment: no, it's MUCH harder to break for a given "key" size. Paradoxically, that's what makes it faster to use, since you don't need as much math to get the same astronomical probabilities for attackers.